# How to play an html 5 video in Cordova iOS app?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, video

I want to **play a little mp4 video** in an html5 page **in my CORDOVA App on iOS**.

Local mp4 can be played but **I can play video stored on remote server**. I dont know why.

=> Is there any config options or element to add to my html page for playing a remote video in CORDOVA iOS app ? See my code here :

HTML page in cordova :

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>TEST</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>TEST APP</h1>
      <video width="320" height="240" controls webkit-playsinline>
         <source src="http://video.tsara-autisme.com/test/010101_360p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <img src="http://video.tsara-autisme.com/test/test.jpg" alt="test"> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Config.xml file :

```xml
...
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://api.tsara-autisme.com/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://video.tsara-autisme.com/*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
...
```

Thanks for help.
Config : Cordova 5.1.1, Xcode 7.2, iOS Simulator 9, iOS 9 on iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the media source in your Content-Security-Policy:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; media-src *;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

You find more infos about Content-Security-Policy at http://content-security-policy.com

Be careful by using the Content-Security-Policy, it is not a good idea to allow everything.

Comment: Ok thanks, but you can see I already use this tag in my HTML page :)

Comment: The tag yes, but not the media-src. ;-))