# Phonegap download / unzip issues with mp3 playing

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I am having issues playing mp3s on my iphone 6 using phonegap.

I am downloading a zip file from the server which contains 1 mp3 file and 3 image files.

All seem to download correctly but I am not too sure about the mp3 file as it just wont play.

To test if the files are there I am doing this:

```
<img src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/audio/1.jpg" alt="" /><br> 
<img src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/audio/2.jpg" alt="" /><br>
<img src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/audio/3.jpg" alt="" /><br>

<a href="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/audio/1.mp3">MP3HERE</a><br>

<audio class="audio" controls>
    <source src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/audio/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

The 3 images show up so I know all the files must be there but although I get the audio player it wont play anything so I created a like too to the mp3 which doesnt play either.

Here is the function I used below:

```
function downloadAndUnzip() {

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.download(
    "http://myserver.com/test.zip",
    "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/audio/test.zip",
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);

        zip.unzip("cdvfile://localhost/persistent/audio/test.zip", 
           "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/audio/", 
           function(){
              alert('Zip decompressed successfully'); //I get this alert

              alert('Checking if test.zip exists');
              checkIfFileExists("/audio/test.zip"); //returns that it exists

              alert('Checking if 1.jpg exists');
              checkIfFileExists("/audio/1.jpg");

              alert('Checking if 2.jpg exists');
              checkIfFileExists("/audio/2.jpg"); //returns that it exists

              alert('Checking if 3.jpg exists');
              checkIfFileExists("/audio/3.jpg"); //returns that it exists

              alert('Checking if 1en.mp3 exists');
              checkIfFileExists("/audio/1.mp3"); //returns that it exists

           }
        );

    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    });

}
```

Now, as far as the alerts go, the zip file was successfully downloads and uncompressed.

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot or fix this?

Comment: You have to enable the media source in your Content-Security-Poilcy. See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374139/how-to-play-an-html-5-video-in-cordova-ios-app/34378964#34378964

Comment: I've added this:   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; media-src *;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"> but mp3 is still not working :/

Comment: I can play audio files only when they are packed within the app but when I download the audio files they just won't play

Comment: I am a bit confused with the fact that mp3 is zipped. What's the benefit? have you tested a "clean" (unzipped) download?

Comment: Yes, I've tried the same code without the unzip part with images, pdf etc and it works fine but when I do this with any audio file it just won't play it. The reason I need to do it will a zip file is that I need to be able to download a zip file with multiple audio files. This is because otherwise the app would be too big to submit to the app store, so I thought the user can download the files after installing the app. Hope this helps

Comment: My idea was to try out an unzipped mp3 downloaded by the app

Comment: I've tried that an it just won't play if it's downloaded via the code only if it's already in the app folder

Comment: @Satch3000, it appears you are using the `<audio (..)>` element. Is this important to you? have you considered other options?

Comment: Well, it's the simplest way. I just don't understand why when files are downloaded it doesn't play but when saved as part of the app it works fine :o/

Comment: Could it be that when the html is loaded the files are not yet available for the case when you download them? Is the html snipped static or you insert it when the files are ready?

Comment: Well, that's what I thought but I then closed the app and reopened it again and it still didn't work. I'm finding it hard to find the logic in the problem

Comment: @Satch3000, What version of iOS are your using? iOS9, iOS8, iOS7? Are you loading any plugins?

Comment: I'm using ios 9 on an iphone 6. As for the plugins I'm using .. here's the list: 
nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin
org.apache.cordova.network-information
org.apache.cordova.device
org.apache.cordova.media
org.apache.cordova.file
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
org.chromium.zip
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Comment: @Satch3000 Did you know that iOS9 is NOT supported by *Phonegap Build*? BTW, you don't put my name in the response. I will not see a flag to your response. This is delaying my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked in my case:

`cdvfile://` did not work for me.

It was all a problem with the path.

In my case using `"cordova.file.dataDirectory"` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem, I wasn't able to show images from the local filesystem.

According to the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file (under cdvfile protocol), I changed the Content Security rules:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
```

Maybe it helps.

**Update for clarification:**

Put

```
<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
```

into the root config.xml file of your project under the widget. It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget ...>
...

 <access origin="cdvfile://*" />

...
</widget>
```

Put in your HTML the Content Security Rules like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
            default-src 'self' data: gap: cdvfile:

...
```

And then make the build with:

```
cordova build
```

Comment: Do I add this: <access origin="cdvfile://*" /> to the config.xml file?

Comment: I tried the above code but for some reason the meta tag --- <meta http-equiv...is making the js code not work properly

Comment: I'm using version: cli-5.2.0  could that be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to copy the unzipped audio files to your desktop machine? Do the play there? The newest cordova has some significant changes, maybe the unzipped files are not correct.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the files on my desktop and they play fine